# Logistic Map closed form for $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n), n\in\mathbb N_0$?

Tags: recursion

$x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n), n\in\mathbb N_0.$ I am only interested in $r=4.$

On Wikipedia I found the following statement:

Every solution $(x_n)^\infty_{n=0}\subset [0,1]$ of the recursion can be written as $x_n=\sin^2(2\pi y_n)$, with $(y_n)^\infty_{n=0}\subset [0,1)$ that satifies $$y_{n+1}=\begin{cases}2y_n & 0 \le y_n < 0.5 \\2y_n -1 & 0.5 \le y_n < 1 \end{cases}$$

How can this be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting together two facts:

- If $x_0$ is in $[0,1]$, there exists $y_0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_0=\sin^2(2\pi y_0)$ (and one can even assume that $y_0$ is in $[0,\frac14]$).
- If $x_n=\sin^2(2\pi y_n)$ for some $n\geqslant0$ and some $y_n$ then 
  $$
  x_{n+1}=4\sin^2(2\pi y_n)\cos^2(2\pi y_n)=\sin^2(4\pi y_n)=\sin^2(2\pi y_{n+1}),
  $$ 
  for every $y_{n+1}$ such that $y_{n+1}-2y_n$ is in $\frac12\mathbb Z$, for example, $y_{n+1}=2y_n\pmod{1}$.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the logistic map $L:[0,1)\to[0,1)$, $x\mapsto4x(1-x)$, is conjugate to the shift $S:\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}\mapsto(a_{n+1})_{n\geqslant1}$, through the binary expansion $B:\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\to[0,1)$, $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}\mapsto\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}a_n2^{-n}$. 
Simply put, this means that 
$$
L\circ B=B\circ S,
$$
and has the consequence that, for every $k\geqslant0$, $L^k$ is encoded by the identity 
$$
L^k\circ B=B\circ S^k,
$$
where $S^k:\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is the shift defined by $S^k((a_n)_{n\geqslant1})=(a_{n+k})_{n\geqslant1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the first part of the statement, I mean why can $x_{n}$ exactly be written as $x_n=sin^2(2\pi y_n)$

Comment: Because $x_0$ is in $[0,1]$, which is the image set of the function $y\mapsto\sin^2(2\pi y)$.

Comment: Thank you. I was just thinking of the following: Assume I write $y_n$ in the binary numeral system: $y_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k,n} \cdot 2^{-k}$ for $a_{k,n}\in\{0,1\}, k\in\mathbb N$, then the recurison equation for $y_n$ should be equivalent to the recursion $a_{k,n+1}=a_{k+1,n}$ for the sequence $(a_{k,n})\subset\{0,1\}$

Comment: Bravo! You (re)discovered the fact that the logistic map $x\mapsto4x(1-x)$ on $[0,1)$ is conjugate to the shift $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}\mapsto(a_{n+1})_{n\geqslant0}$ on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could explain me this equivalence a little bit more in detail.

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: It helped me a lot, thank you. But I have a last question (It is really the last one). Wikipedia also states that if I have an arbitrary number $m\in\mathbb N$ then there exists a periodic point $x\in[0,1]$, such that the lenght of the period = m. How can this be followed from our equivalence between the recursion and the binary numbers ?

Comment: The point $x=\sin^2(2\pi y)$ is periodic with period $m$ if $\sin^2(2\pi 2^my)=\sin^2(2\pi y)$ and all the $\sin^2(2\pi2^ky)$ for $0\leqslant k\leqslant m-1$ are different. Solve this for $y$, deduce $x$.

Comment: I solved $sin^2(2π2^m y)=sin^2(2πy)$ for y (wolfram alpha gets 4 solutions), $y=\frac{2n+1}{2^{m+1}+2}, n\in\mathbb Z$ How can I deduce x now?

Comment: I don't understand: you ask for an $m$-periodic point, I give you one. What more do you want? Just in case, let me suggest you re-read slowly my post and comments. (And why one would turn to W|A to solve the equation I gave you beats me.)