# Can I use integral calculus to derive the closed form of a logistic map?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I've read various threads about the logistic map (Verhulst's equation) including:

[closed form solutions for the logistic map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185592/closed-form-solutions-for-the-logistic-map)

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1560.pdf

[Logistic Map closed form for $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n), n\in\mathbb N_0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226033/logistic-map-closed-form-for-x-n1-rx-n1-x-n-n-in-mathbb-n-0)

And they all mention that closed form solutions only exist for specific values of r. But what is wrong with the following reasoning:

\begin{gathered}
{{x}({n}{+}{1})\hspace{0.33em}{=}\hspace{0.33em}{r}{*}\hspace{0.33em}{x}({n}){(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{-}{x}({n}){)}}\\
\\but
\\{{x}({n}{+}{1})\hspace{0.33em}{=}\hspace{0.33em}{dx}\hspace{0.33em}{+}{x}({n})}\\
\\substituting\hspace{0.33em}gives   \\
\\
{{dx}\hspace{0.33em}{+}{x}({n}){=}\hspace{0.33em}{r}{*}\hspace{0.33em}{x}({n}){(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{-}{x}({n}){)}}\\
\\subtracting\hspace{0.33em}{x}({n})\hspace{0.33em}from\hspace{0.33em}both\hspace{0.33em}sides
\\
\\{{dx}\hspace{0.33em}{=}\hspace{0.33em}{r}{*}\hspace{0.33em}{x}({n}){(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{-}{x}({n}){)}\hspace{0.33em}{-}\hspace{0.33em}{x}({n})}\\
\\we \hspace{0.33em}know\hspace{0.33em}that\\
{{f}{(}{x}{)}\hspace{0.33em}{=}\int{dx}}\\
{{f}{(}{x}{)}\hspace{0.33em}{=}\hspace{0.33em}\int{{r}{*}\hspace{0.33em}{x}{(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{-}{x}{)}\hspace{0.33em}{-}\hspace{0.33em}{x}}}\\
{{f}{(}{x}{)}\hspace{0.33em}{=}\hspace{0.33em}{-}\frac{1}{6}{x}^{2}\left({{3}{+}{r}\left({{-}{3}{+}{2}{x}}\right)}\right)}
\end{gathered}

Clearly, I am missing something HUGE. I know integration is over the set of real numbers whereas Verhulst's equation is intended for integers. But is that a significant difference? If something is valid for the set of real numbers then it should be valid for the set of integers, which is just a subset.

Comment: "If something is valid for the set of real numbers then it should be valid for the set of integers, which is just a subset." This is _very, very_ much not true.

Comment: Differentiation depends fundamentally on the fact that $dx\to 0$, which does not occur in the integers.